# Natural Isomorphism: how can $A \otimes B \simeq B \otimes A $ and yet $A \otimes B \neq B \otimes A $

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, monoidal-categories

I am reading [Braided Monoidal Categories](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/JS1.pdf) by Joyal and Street.  They say cateogories with tensor product arise naturally such as the category of [Abelian Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) and that of [Banach Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space).

Is there any example where: $A \otimes B \simeq B \otimes A $ and  yet $A \otimes B \neq B \otimes A $ ?   Maybe I am not reading far enough into the paper.

The examples in section 2 use categories of ribbons or braids.  I would like to see instances of "ribbon-ness" or "braiding" arising from Algebra or Topology.

Comment: A simple example would be the non-strict symmetric monoidal category of vector spaces equipped with the usual tensor product.

Comment: Question: for two sets $A$ and $B$, is $A \times B = B \times A$?

Comment: Or, to put it more emphatically: the vast majority of "real-world" examples of symmetric monoidal categories do _not_ satisfy $A \otimes B = B \otimes A$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask if two objects are equal. The correct notion of equality is isomorphism (+ coherence issues). See also http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vertical+categorification

Answer (score 3):

In general it is very rare for a braided monoidal category to commute "on the nose". For a very concrete example, the usual category of sets and functions is cartesian monoidal, so braided (even symmetric) monoidal, but in general $A \times B \neq B \times A$.

As for the braids, there is a PRO (monoidal category with $\mathbb{N}$ as the set of objects and $+$ as product) where the morphisms are the braid groups. This construction is even the universal braided monoidal category (**Edit:** It's actually the free braided monoidal category on one object. I was just repeating what my category theory professor said.), and appears at a number of places in physics for example. The braid groups arise from topology as the fundamental group of a certain configuration space (see [the formal treatment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Formal_treatment) and the book *Braid Groups* by Christian Kassel and Vladimir Tuarev).

The ribbons arise when, intuitively, the braids are allowed to twist on themselves, just like the half-twist for the Möbius band. Unfortunately, I am not very familar with this added generalization.

Comment: "... universal braided monoidal category". It is the free braided monoidal category on one object.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg But it still has some universal property, doesn't it? Like the simplicial category?

Comment: I have just specified the universal property...